# logic of introducing varuable in fibnacci, javascript

Tags: javascript

please could somebody explain me how a computer gets to know in this code that the variable "i" somehow refers to the array fib?I don't really understand the logic of this

```js
function fibb(n) {
  var fib = [];
  if (n === 1) {
    fib = [0];
  } else
  if (n === 2) {
    fib = [0, 1];
  } else {
    fib = [0, 1];
    for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
      fib.push(fib[fib.length - 2] + fib[fib.length - 1]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Not seeing a return value. Did you paste all the code?

Comment: `i` never refers to `fib`.

Comment: _"that the variable "i" somehow refers to the array fib"_ - `i` has nothing to do with `fib` nor is it used to access/modify the elements in `fib`

Comment: And please fix the format of the (incomplete) function. It's hard to read and follow its flow of the code.

Comment: Looks like a teacher said "fix this" code. And now lets welcome froggy

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are new to programming. In the code `i` never refers to the array `fib`. What is happening is that the `for` loop is iterating the inner instructions n-2 times, and the inner instruction is written in such a way that in never needs to be pointed by `i`. The loop inside always adds the last 2 numbers of the `fib` array and appends in `fib` array.